# Scaling Height Displacement Map from GIS Data

Tags: transforms, displacement, height-map

I am working for a documentary film project that is seeking to accurately scale bathymetry data of California's lakes in Blender to create some simple animations of lakebeds/terrain.

So far, I have been using a .tif file from ArcGIS as an image texture to dictate the height displacement of a mesh.

See shader nodes below:
[image: shader nodes image]

As you can see, I have linked an image texture node's color to the height of the displacement node linked to the displacement of the output. Initially after doing so, at a displacement scale of 1 and midlevel of 0.5, the .tif file of the lakebed overlayed the mesh looks like this:
[image: displacement on mesh with scale of 1]

Obviously, this is very unusable. The scale of the height displacement is so drastically high that it just creates a massive column instead of a detailed mesh terrain.

Fiddling with the height displacement scale in the displacement node, I can get the map to look somewhat realistic.[image: scaled down displacement map]

Doing it this way, by eye, is irrelevent though because a map like this can't be used for our final product. The visual accuracy of these animations is very important to the film. **I am at a loss for how to scale the displacement height derived from the .tif file accurately to represent the geographical data that it shows if I render it in a program like ArcGIS.** Like I said, I can scale it by eye, but a model scaled this way can't be used for my purposes because we need the height displacement to accurately represent the gathered data.

Below are the displacement settings I was using:

[image: displacement settings]

"Object Space"

"Pass index: 0"

"Multiple Importance"

"Transparent Shadows"

"Displacement and Bump"

"Sampling: Multiple Importance"

"Interpolation: Linear"

"Not homogeneous"

"Step Rate: 1"

I have had to scale it so far down that I was at -0.000000001 for scale. I still had no idea if this was accurate though, it just looked better than the stairway to heaven I had accidentally created before.

Before this project, I have only used blender for artistic purposes not requiring it to be geographically accurate. I am totally out of my wheelhouse here so any help I could get with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: -0.000000001 for scale? Stupid question, how large was the object you used the height map on and was the scale applied?

Comment: The object was just the generic plane mesh, not scaled, original size. The scale was only pertaining to the amount of displacement applied.